# Not able to view pdf in react native using accordion

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-paper

In react native I am using `react-native-paper` and `react-native-view-pdf` to show pdf in accordion on react native paper.

Below is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native";
import { List } from "react-native-paper";
import PDFView from "react-native-view-pdf";

const PDFAccordion = () => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

  const handlePress = () => {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  };

  return (
    <List.Section title="Accordions">
      <List.Accordion
        title="Controlled Accordion"
        left={(props) => <List.Icon {...props} icon="folder" />}
        expanded={expanded}
        onPress={handlePress}
        children={renderContent}
      >
        <View style={styles.pdfContainer}>
        <Text>hi</Text>
          <PDFView
            fadeInDuration={250.0}
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            resource={"http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf"}
          />
        </View>
      </List.Accordion>
    </List.Section>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  pdfContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
  },
});

export default PDFAccordion;
```

My accordion is working, I can see hi text, but I cant see pdf in that.